# MVC How to insert data into list inside model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am using MVC and razor, and I have two models:

```
public class bookModel {
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string title {get;set;}
  public List<otherStuff> stuff {get;set}
}
public class otherStuff {
  public string text {get;set;}
  public int page {get;set;}
}
```

How can I insert `stuff` into `otherStuff` from the View? 
The view looks something like this:

```
@model name.models.bookModel
@using (html.beginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, null)){
  @html.textBox("title")
  ...
}
```

and the Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult action (bookModel model) {
  //do something
}
```

At this point I can get access to the title. But I still haven't found out how to insert `stuff` into the `ortherStuff` and get access to it inside of the action.

Comment: The default model passing / handling is not good for non-simple objects. You could use the session... Session["BookModel"] = bookmodel, use it in the view -  bookModel myBookModel = (bookModel)Session["BookModel"]; myBookModel.stuff[0].page etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the `List<otherStuff>` in the View and output the controls like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.stuff.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.stuff[i].text)
}
```

The controls will be rendered with an index in the name, like this:

```
<input name="stuff[3].text" type="text" etc..
```

When you POST to the controller, you can iterate over the submitted `stuff` data like so:

```
foreach (var item in model.stuff)
{
}
```